# Pyside2.QtCore.QObject isn't a direct base class of MyTableWidget -- Error with PySide2

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside2

I have a C++ background, so perhaps I don't understand Python classes well enough, but in my code I get the above error. I am trying to learn PySide2 and Qt, and I took this code from a PyQt tutorial. As far as I know, these are API compatible, except for a couple things that I fixed, so this should work.

The code I am using is below:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtCore import Slot

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Tabbed window'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300,200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")

        # Create first tab
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton("Button")
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton1)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @Slot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("\n")
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It should be `super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)`, but if you're using python3, you can just do `super().__init__(parent)` (see: [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)).

Comment: Sorry, what is `currentQTableWidgetItem` and `self.qtableWidget`?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, as [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) said, the problem lies on the `super` call, and you need to make a reference to `MyTableWidget` instead of `QWidget`.

Usually in Python classes that inherit from another you have three options (considering Python 3). I recommend you to pick one and stick with it ;)

```
class Base():
    ...
class Derived(Base):
    ...


# Getting the super class (explicit)
super(Derived, self).__init__(...)

# Getting the super class (implicit)
super().__init__(...)

# Call the parent directly
Base.__init__(...)
```